# How to set an optional string as text in UiTextLabel?

Tags: swift, option-type, word-wrap

I have string name which seems to be an optional name. I need to set that to the textlabel. But this somehow does not seem to work as in the UI the text is not set.
when I print out the string unwrapped it looks fine.
But when I set the string unwrapped to the uitextlabel.text and print that one out, it seems to be not good as still the keyword optional appears.
How can I assign this string unwrapped to the uitextlabel.text correctly?

```
var name : String?

 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    print("School detail view loaded and print address")


    let rect = view.bounds

    //set header and footer
  //  schoolNameLabel.text = "set value 1"
 //   print(schoolNameLabel.text )

    if let unwrapped = self.name {
        print("print unwrapped")
        print(unwrapped)

        schoolNameLabel.text = unwrapped
        print("print label.text")
        print(schoolNameLabel.text)

    }
```

Output on console:

```
print unwrapped
Milner college

print label.text
Optional("Milner college")
```

Comment: The key word `Optional` in the console is just to say that you object is an Optional object (can be `nil`). You have nothing to do with it. Whenever you show the content of this object, whatever it has value or not, the console will show: `Optional("xxxx")``

Answer (score 2):

You have no need to do it. I assume your `schoolNameLabel` is a `UILabel`.
The property `text` of `UILabel` is declared as:

```
var text: String?
```

([UILabel Class Reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UILabel_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UILabel/text))

So, any non-Optional `String` is automatically converted to `String?`. Although `print` always encloses the actual content with "Optional(" & ")" for non-nil values, `UILabel` shows it's actual content without "Optional".

And if "shows nothing when `nil`" is what you want, you have no need to unwrap `String?`.

Just assign `self.name` to `schoolNameLabel.text` directly:

```
    schoolNameLabel.text = self.name
```

It never crashes your app, and just "shows nothing", even if `self.name` is `nil`.

Answer (score 1):

```
if let unwrapped = self.name! {
```

try to save it in unwrapped really as unwrapped so don't miss "!"

Answer (score 0):

```
print(schoolNameLabel.text!) //add this ! optional sign.. becuase that textfiled text value may be null
```